# Sorting Twig array by day of given date

Tags: sorting, twig

I'd like to sort an array (`nextbirthdays`) by a date value which is given. Unlike just ordering the date itself, I'd like to sort by the day given. In this case I'd like to display the birthdays of users. The dataset given only contains users with their birthday of today plus 7 days.

the dataset itself could look something like this:

```
 Birthday     | Username
--------------+-----------
 01. Apr 1953 | User 1         
 04. Apr 1970 | User 2
 02. Apr 1992 | User 3
 02. Apr 2002 | User 4
 01. Apr 1993 | User 5
```

When using `nextbirthdays|sort` twig correctly sorts the dates (by newest to olderst or the other way around) but I'd like to sort by the actual day, then month, then year of the date.

```
 Birthday     | Username
--------------+-----------
 01. Apr 1993 | User 5      
 01. Apr 1953 | User 1
 02. Apr 2002 | User 4
 02. Apr 1992 | User 3
 04. Apr 1970 | User 2
```

Original Code:

```
<ul>
{% for nextbd in nextbirthdays %}
    <li><span class="text-muted mr-3">{{ nextbd.birthday|date("d. M Y") }}: </span>

    {% if nextbd.birthday|date("d.m") == "now"|date("d.m") %}
        <b>{{ nextbd.firstname }} {{ nextbd.lastname }}</b>
    {% else %}
        {{ nextbd.firstname }} {{ nextbd.lastname }}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sort & Map:

When trying to adapt the sort function from twig using the statement below the birthdays don't show up anymore.

```
{% for nextbd in nextbirthdays|sort((a, b) => a.birthday <=> b.birthday)|column('birthday') %}
    <!-- rest of the code is unchanged -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have two issues in your code:

1. `|column('birthday')`: using this filter, you'll limit your array to the column `birthday` only, so you won't get the first or last name anymore.
2. Your requirement is more complex than what you think it is:

   - `01. Apr` sorted before `02. Apr` means your are doing an ascending sort on the day and month
   - `01. Apr 1993` sorted before `01. Apr 1953` means you are doing a descending sorting on the year

So, your condition should be:

```
a.birthday|date('dm') > b.birthday|date('dm') or (a.birthday|date('dm') == b.birthday|date('dm') and a.birthday|date('Y') < b.birthday|date('Y'))
```

Giving a for loop:

```
{% for nextbd in nextbirthdays|sort((a, b) => a.birthday|date('dm') > b.birthday|date('dm') or (a.birthday|date('dm') == b.birthday|date('dm') and a.birthday|date('Y') < b.birthday|date('Y'))) %}
  {# rest of the code is unchanged #}
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>*This can be tested here: https://twigfiddle.com/of3cbi*</sup>